# Additional virtual security?

Tags: virtualization, compliance

Besides following VMware's security best practices, are there any other recommended security technologies that are aimed at security and compliance in virtual environments? Vormetric comes to mind, but are there other recommended third party solutions?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based **and** too broad, am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Security Best Practice" depends on many factors since your control environment (e.g. Health Care, Payment Systems, etc.) will have different regulations and standards that must be followed. (e.g. HIPAA, PCI-DSS, etc.)

> Besides following VMware's security best practices

I'm assuming that you mean the hardening guides available here: https://www.vmware.com/security/hardening-guides

If that is the case, those are mainly technical controls - very good controls to implement if you can -  and do not cover many of the controls outlined in something like ISO 27001/2 or COBIT. Again, how far and deep you need to go with security and compliance depends on your control environment.

> are there any other recommended security technologies that are aimed
>   at security and compliance in virtual environments?

VMware offers some free compliance checkers for things like the Hardening Guide (mentioned above), DISA, and HIPAA - I recommend these to get started. There is a PCI checker tool but it is a bit outdated:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=compliance-chk

In order to narrow down what is best for your control environment, I would suggest looking for white papers in your industry. I did a quick search for "vmware security partners" and saw that Symantec has an offering to help with security and compliance - ***Control Compliance Suite*** - http://www.symantec.com/control-compliance-suite

For specific security improvements there are products like McAfee MOVE that moves the antivirus scanning load to the hypervisor instead of the virtual machine.

http://www.mcafee.com/us/products/move-anti-virus.aspx

Also note that what you can do with VMware and 3rd party offerings depends on the type of licensing you have as well - if you are not using Enterprise for example there might be some "gotchas" along the way. For example if you need a distributed switch, which is required for something like NSX, then you must have an enterprise license. The Symantec Control Compliance Suite that I mentioned above also requires a VMware Enterprise license.

I don't think you will find an all encompassing solution but a good strategy would be to understand your threats and control environment, perform a gap assessment, analyze the amount of effort required to remediate (i.e. mitigate, accept, transfer the risks) the gaps, and *then* see if there is a 3rd party solution that can help save you time and money in remediating the risks that must be mitigated.